# SSO configured as per docs and API works fine on Postman but only gets errors on the actual app and emulator

Tags: buildfire

Using this (https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Using-Single-Sign-On-(SSO)), a WordPress-based OAuth server and using Postman as well to make sure that the API is responding as expected. I even went so far as to whitelist the specific URLs from the firewall.

I'm only seeing a generic "Error while testing SSO Login" in the emulator and on the actual app, we get "Invalid Login" errors.

Using the same credentials in Postman works as expected.

Comment: What logs do you see in the Control Panel > Settings > Auth Settings > SSO Testing console?

Comment: Just "Error while testing SSO Login" which is rather unhelpful. We've temporarily disabled the login for now.